# ESLINT: no-unused-vars, stream conditional pipe use case

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, chaining, eslint

So i have the following function:

```
function buildJavaScript(file) {
    var manifestRoot,
        stream;

    validateManifestSection(file.manifest, 'javascript');

    if (file.manifest.javascript.disabled) {
        return;
    }

    manifestRoot = path.dirname(file.path);
    stream = gulp.src(path.join(manifestRoot, file.manifest.javascript.src))
        .pipe(gulpBrowserify())
        .pipe(gulpRename(file.manifest.javascript.dest));

    if (file.manifest.javascript.minify) {
        stream = stream.pipe(gulpUglify());
    }

    stream = stream.pipe(gulp.dest(manifestRoot));
}
```

Its purpose is part of a gulp task, receives an object representing a manifest file then `browserifies` and conditionally `uglifies` it.

Now when i ESLint it i get the following error:

```
error no-unused-vars : 'stream' is defined but never used.
```

NOTE: i don't make common practice of linting my build files, this was part of testing the linter and its behavior here caught my attention.

I get that you need more than just assignment for it to be satisfied which is a good thing otherwise it could be easily fooled.

However in the instance above where the variable is a stream and assignment and chaining is enough to warrant use how do you get ESLint to be happy?

Or am i doing it wrong and that is not how your meant to conditionally pipe a stream?

I get if i was to return `stream` or pass it into another method it would please the linter but that doesn't seem right, i don't need to return it for use elsewhere.

Thanks for any help or insights.

EDIT:

In trying to pinpoint the issue ive reduced the method down to the following which still has the issue:

```
function buildJavaScript(file) {
    var stream;

    stream = gulp
        .src(path.join('', file.manifest.javascript.src))
        .pipe(gulpBrowserify())
        .pipe(gulpRename(file.manifest.javascript.dest));

    if (file.manifest.javascript.minify) {
        stream = stream.pipe(gulpUglify());
    }
}
```

I can understand its reasoning, technically all I am doing is assignment, not consumption elsewhere but its the context of the assignment which means the variable is being used.

Comment: Have you already tried removing the if with return statement and check if eslint is happy ? It seems the only thing that makes "stream" not used.

Comment: @Pietro yep, ill add to the question what ive tried reducing it down to, too big for a comment.

Comment: the only "consuming" I see in you second code is `stream = stream.pipe(gulpUglify());` my question is: is the linter happy if you remove the last if and pipe the uglify "always" ?

Comment: @Pietro No the linter still complains. Looking through the [docs](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#rule-details) it is conforming to exactly what they say it should, all im doing is assignment. So am i doing something wrong if i wanted this sort of conditional chaining to be linted?

Comment: Interesting behavior, I agree with you, i'll follow this post to see if anyone had already this issue ;) Good luck! :)

Comment: This looks like a bug! I filed an issue on GitHub so we can get it fixed: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7282

Comment: @btmills brilliant thanks, I'm always wary of asking 'support' question on Github. Ill keeps tabs on it and post back here when a resolution is found.